# PHPMyAdmin and Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin, url-rewriting

I use a very specifical configuration in Nginx for rewriting URL but then it blocks /phpmyadmin.

I've tried tons of different ways for making pma back but not any worked..

Please help me make PMA works with this configuration for url rewriting in WP :

```
server 
{
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /var/www;
    # Static
    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    # PHP scripts -> PHP-FPM server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
             # The following line prevents malicious php code to be executed through some uploaded file (without php extension, like image)
             # This fix shoudn't work though, if nginx and php are not on the same server, other options exist (like unauthorizing php execution within upload folder)
             # More on this serious security concern in the "Pass Non-PHP Requests to PHP" section, there http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
             try_files $uri =404;

             fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
             fastcgi_index  index.php;
             include fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # Security
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Stuffs
    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log   off;
        return   204;
    }
    rewrite ^/wp-admin$ /wp-admin/ permanent;
    if (-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_2 1;
    }
    if (-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_2 1;
    }
    if ($rule_2 = "1"){
    }
    rewrite ^/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /$1 last;
    rewrite ^/(.*.php)$ /$1 last;
    rewrite /. /index.php last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second-to-last rewrite rule is going to take ANY string including at least one character and "php" and redirect it. This is because the second `.` is not escaped, so it's a wildcard, not a literal dot. Try

```
rewrite ^/(.*\.php)$ /$1 last;
```

and see if that helps.

On a more general approach: Why not create a second server block in your nginx configuration and point a subdomain at it, e.g. db.mysite.com ? Extra bonus is that if you define the subdomain locally (e.g. in `/etc/hosts`) instead of in public DNS, anyone without that subdomain definition will never see your phpmyadmin installation. And you can get around all these headaches of trying to run phpmyadmin on the same virtual host as a public server.

Comment: Tried but nothing change.. For the DNS, problem is that i've in my DNS settings a wilcard *.domain.tld for multi-sites on WP..

Comment: This is specially this that cause problem  : rewrite /. /index.php last; When I comment out other rewrite instructions (like the one that you gave me) won't change anything. When I comment the one mentioned before, PMA is ok but my url rewriting on MP failed..